# Accessing Javascript objects in Jade from Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, pug

I want to write a simple website that uses the GoogleMaps JavaScript API. I am using Node.js as the backend, and using Jade to write the HTML. According to Google's documentations, the JavaScript used to obtain the GoogleMaps object is embedded in HTML (in Jade in this case). However, I want to manipulate that object in the backend, but I don't know how to access JavaScript objects defined in the HTML/Jade file from 'index.js'. Please help. Thanks

- I saw someone saying that I should use Socket.IO, is that a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the question, but I *think* what you want to do is have your server grab the GoogleMaps file with an HTTP client request:

https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest

Then you can fiddle with it all you want before you respond to the request.